# List of automorphism groups of low-dimensional complex commutative algebras?

Tags: reference-request, gr.group-theory, ac.commutative-algebra, algebraic-groups, associative-algebras

Let $\mathcal{A}$ be a finite-dimensional commutative associative unital $\mathbb{C}$-algebra. I am looking for a list (of further examples of) $\operatorname{Aut}_\mathbb{C}(\mathcal{A})$, the group of $\mathbb{C}$-algebra automorphisms of $\mathcal{A}$ for low $\dim_\mathbb{C} \mathcal{A}$. It doesn't need to contain the actual computations (though that would be nice too), I just need a list with a few examples. I distinctly remember seeing such computations somewhere, but for the life of me I can't remember/find the source. For instance, it's not difficult to check that $\operatorname{Aut}_\mathbb{C}(\mathbb{C}[x]/(x^2)) \cong \mathbb{C}^\times$.

Comment: For a finite-dimensional algebra $A$, a computer can quickly compute the Lie algebra $\mathrm{Der}(A)$, which is the Lie algebra of $\mathrm{Aut}(A)$. This does not exactly determine $\mathrm{Aut}(A)$ but this is not very far.

Comment: @YCor: Thanks! Can you suggest software that can do this?

Comment: I don't know (but this seems not hard to implement, e.g. in Python/SageMath, since a $n$-dim algebra is input by $n^3$ structure constants, and being a derivation consists in computing the set of solutions of a system of $n^3$ equations on $n^2$ variables, this system depending linearly on the "vector" of structure constants).